# Isotope loading and responsive margin in a Wordpress theme

Tags: wordpress-theming, lazy-loading, jquery-isotope

I am actually working on a Wordpress project using Isotope http://isotope.metafizzy.co/
Here is my site : http://ocedille.virtualibrary.fr

I've created my own Wordpress template and globally everything is working as I expected. But some details are not right....I am quite desperate to find a solution.

Well, first I have to explain you what's wrong :

- When I load the site, you can see all my images in full size loading for a few seconds....that is so ugly!! what can I do to make it invisible?
- Then all my images/items appears on the same line. When I put the cursor of my mouse on it, all the images move and take the right place...I would like that my images take the right place at the very beginning too!!!
- And how can I have the same responsive, horizontal and vertical, margins between my items?
  I succeed to do it verticaly with this following code:

  $container.isotope({
                              itemSelector: '.item',
                              // options...
                              resizable: false, // disable normal resizing
                              // set columnWidth to a percentage of container width
                              masonry: { 
                                  columnWidth: $container.width() / 3
                              },
                          });

  ```
                      // update columnWidth on window resize
                      $(window).smartresize(function(){
                          $container.isotope({
                              // update columnWidth to a percentage of container width
                              masonry: { 
                                  columnWidth: $container.width() / 3
                              },
                          });
                      });
  ```

How can I do the same thing horizontally? (maybe with rowHeight but I did'nt succeed to make it work!)

Please be cool, this is my first Jquery/JS project! I am not an expert and I am here to learn! I tried to find my answer on a lot of forums before asking here but I did'nt find my exact need...I hope you can help me!

Thanks for your help!!

NB: Sorry for my english, I am french...so that's not my native langage. I hope you'll understand me!

/**********EDIT**********/

I think I found a solution for my first issue.

> When I load the site, you can see all my images in full size loading for a few seconds....that is so ugly!! what can I do to make it invisible?

I added the following code :

CSS

```
#primary { 
display:none;}
```

HTML

```
<div id="wait"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/loader.gif" alt="loading" /></div>
```

JS

```
$("#wait").hide();
$("#primary").fadeIn();
```

That's an easy preloader and now I think that I don't have the ugly effect on the load of the page

Do you think that's a good solution? Is there a better one?

And do you have answers for my other issues!?

thx